# Turning documentation examples into tests for python command line tools

Tags: python, command-line-interface, doctest

With the [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) module, there exists a nice tool to turn interactive examples in documentation into tests of python modules.
This is fine for library-like code, but I am working on a command line tool, reading and writing small files according to the option provided with the command.

Is there something similar to turn usage examples of such a command line tool into tests?

Comment: Feels like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088556/testing-command-line-utilities . Obviously you should treat these as _acceptance_ or _integration_ tests, they are not alternative to unit tests, but their complement.

Comment: That question looks like half what I want, I may have to build the other half myself by expanding doctest, because I really want to write a tutorial, and not a tutorial and some * tests that will start deviating from each other the moment they are complete.